# CSS not working in flask app on apache2 server

Tags: html, css, apache, python-3.x

I have a simple flask app which uses a css style sheet. The app is being severed by an apache2 server running on a raspberry pi.

The main index html page shows but with no styling.

The set up is as follows:
In the index.html i have

```
<link href="{{url_for('static', filename='main.css')  }}" >
```

In the flask app i have

```
app.static_folder = 'static'
```

The folder structure is

```
/var/www/Flask/
/var/www/Flask/AlPiBanner/
/var/www/Flask/AlPiBanner/static
/var/www/Flask/AlPiBanner/templates
```

In the /var/www/Flask folder i have the wsgi file AlPiBanner.wsgi
and ion the  AlPiBanner folder the **init**.py file

I have searched the web and read several articles on this site that seem to indicate that it should work, so I'm not sure what I'm missing

any help would be appreciated.

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by adding the static directory into the flask app.conf
`<Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/Static/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>`